# AnyObject property in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a question about property of AnyObject in Swift. I have some method with AnyObject variable. I can check what type is it, but for example I want to perform an operation on property regardless of the type of the variable (all possible types have the same property). Is that possible to call this varaiable?

Comment: What property are you referring to that all objects have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In almost all cases, an `AnyObject` property is a mistake. Almost always a protocol or generic was the right tool. For example, if you want to perform an operation "regardless of the type" then you really mean this type has some characteristic that would allow you to perform that operation. That characteristic (for instance, the existence of some property) is usually best expressed as a protocol.

Answer (score 3):

AnyObject is used for compatibility with Cocoa and Objective C.

Comment: While ObjC has several data structures that tend to generate AnyObject (such as non-generic NSDictionary), there are a number of cases where AnyObject pops up in Swift having nothing to do with ObjC. Certainly less common, but even if Cocoa had never existed, there would still need to be Any/AnyObject.

Comment: When working with generics and weak references in swift you will need to make sure the type conforms to a swift class which is represented by AnyObject.  No way to avoid it as far as I know.